# How to use Spark-SQL query for implementing conditional statement?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, conditional-statements, cdc

I am using spark 2.0, developing using scala and want to implement a conditional statement to populate a table. The purpose is to carry out Change Data Capture (CDC). Please see the pseudo code below to have better understanding.

```
val rawDataPartition = "select partition_date from rawDataTableName limit 1";

if(value_of_rawDataPartition == current_timestamp()) {
//Logic for CDC 
} else {
//Load the empty table as its first time load
}
```

How can I do this?

Edit:

Following piece of code works fine with small tables but is creating memory issues (mentioned after code) and hence failing when dataframe is large (281 columns in my case).

```
    //function for uniform null values
       def replace(Colm :Column) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column= {
              return when(Colm==="null" || Colm==="NULL" || Colm==="" || 
        Colm==="Null" || Colm==="\\N",lit(null)).otherwise(Colm)
       }

val rawdata_sql = "select  "+ rawDataTableColumns + ",md5(concat_ws(''," + rawDataTableStrColumns+")) as Hash_Column, current_timestamp as LAST_MDF_DT from "+ rawDataTableName + " where partition_date='" + folderDate + "'" 
var batch_data = hqlContext.sql(rawdata_sql).toDF()
batch_data.dtypes.foreach { f => 
val fName = f._1
val fType = f._2
if (fType == "StringType") {
batch_data=batch_data.withColumn(fName,replace(col(fName)))
}}
```

Error Produced:

```
TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 2, ICDCA0000020.cn.isn.corpintra.net): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: failed to compile: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Code of method "(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Z" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate" grows beyond 64 KB
/* 001 */ public SpecificPredicate generate(Object[] references) {
/* 002 */   return new SpecificPredicate(references);
/* 003 */ }
/* 004 */
/* 005 */ class SpecificPredicate extends org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.Predicate {
/* 006 */   private final Object[] references;
/* 007 */
/* 008 */
/* 009 */
/* 010 */   public SpecificPredicate(Object[] references) {
/* 011 */     this.references = references;
/* 012 */
/* 013 */   }
/* 014 */
/* 015 */   public boolean eval(InternalRow i) {
/* 016 */
/* 017 */     boolean isNull2 = true;
/* 018 */     UTF8String value2 = null;
/* 019 */
/* 020 */
/* 021 */     boolean isNull7 = false;
/* 022 */
/* 023 */     boolean isNull8 = false;
/* 024 */
/* 025 */     Object obj = ((Expression) references[0]).eval(null);
/* 026 */     UTF8String value11 = (UTF8String) obj;
/* 027 */
/* 028 */     boolean isNull12 = i.isNullAt(126);
/* 029 */     UTF8String value12 = isNull12 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(126));
/* 030 */
/* 031 */     boolean isNull13 = i.isNullAt(225);
/* 032 */     UTF8String value13 = isNull13 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(225));
/* 033 */
/* 034 */     boolean isNull14 = i.isNullAt(47);
/* 035 */     UTF8String value14 = isNull14 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(47));
/* 036 */
/* 037 */     boolean isNull15 = i.isNullAt(44);
/* 038 */     UTF8String value15 = isNull15 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(44));
/* 039 */
/* 040 */     boolean isNull16 = i.isNullAt(258);
/* 041 */     UTF8String value16 = isNull16 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(258));
/* 042 */
/* 043 */     boolean isNull17 = i.isNullAt(91);
/* 044 */     UTF8String value17 = isNull17 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(91));
/* 045 */
/* 046 */     boolean isNull18 = i.isNullAt(71);
/* 047 */     UTF8String value18 = isNull18 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(71));
/* 048 */
/* 049 */     boolean isNull19 = i.isNullAt(140);
/* 050 */     UTF8String value19 = isNull19 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(140));
/* 051 */
/* 052 */     boolean isNull21 = i.isNullAt(166);
/* 053 */     long value21 = isNull21 ? -1L : (i.getLong(166));
/* 054 */     boolean isNull20 = isNull21;
/* 055 */     UTF8String value20 = null;
/* 056 */     if (!isNull21) {
/* 057 */       value20 = UTF8String.fromString(
/* 058 */         org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils.timestampToString(value21));
/* 059 */     }
/* 060 */
/* 061 */     boolean isNull23 = i.isNullAt(167);
/* 062 */     long value23 = isNull23 ? -1L : (i.getLong(167));
/* 063 */     boolean isNull22 = isNull23;
.....
..
..
..
.
/* 9893 */         boolean isNull2620 = i.isNullAt(126);
/* 9894 */         UTF8String value2620 = isNull2620 ? null : (i.getUTF8String(126));
/* 9895 */         isNull2599 = isNull2620;
/* 9896 */         value2599 = value2620;
/* 9897 */       }
/* 9898 */       value = (!(isNull2599));
/* 9899 */     }
/* 9900 */     return !false && value;
/* 9901 */   }
/* 9902 */ }

        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:950)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:947)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
        at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Code of method "(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Z" of class "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificPredicate" grows beyond 64 KB
        at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.makeSpace(CodeContext.java:941)
        at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.write(CodeContext.java:854)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.writeShort(UnitCompiler.java:10242)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.store(UnitCompiler.java:9939)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.store(UnitCompiler.java:9921)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet2(UnitCompiler.java:5081)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$12100(UnitCompiler.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$15.visitLocalVariableAccess(UnitCompiler.java:5065)
        at org.codehaus.janino.Java$LocalVariableAccess.accept(Java.java:3186)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet(UnitCompiler.java:5070)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet2(UnitCompiler.java:5077)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$11600(UnitCompiler.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$15.visitLocalVariableAccess(UnitCompiler.java:5065)
        at org.codehaus.janino.Java$LocalVariableAccess.accept(Java.java:3186)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet(UnitCompiler.java:5070)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet2(UnitCompiler.java:5077)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$11600(UnitCompiler.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$15.visitAmbiguousName(UnitCompiler.java:5060)
        at org.codehaus.janino.Java$AmbiguousName.accept(Java.java:3141)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileSet(UnitCompiler.java:5070)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:2675)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$4500(UnitCompiler.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$7.visitAssignment(UnitCompiler.java:2619)
        at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Assignment.accept(Java.java:3405)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:2654)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:1643)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$1100(UnitCompiler.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$4.visitExpressionStatement(UnitCompiler.java:936)
        at org.codehaus.janino.Java$ExpressionStatement.accept(Java.java:2097)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:958)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileStatements(UnitCompiler.java:1007)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile2(UnitCompiler.java:993)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.access$1000(UnitCompiler.java:185)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler$4.visitBlock(UnitCompiler.java:935)
        at org.codehaus.janino.Java$Block.accept(Java.java:2012)
        at org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compile(UnitCompiler.java:2293)
        ...
        at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.compileToClass(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.janino.ClassBodyEvaluator.cook(ClassBodyEvaluator.java:233)
        at org.codehaus.janino.SimpleCompiler.cook(SimpleCompiler.java:192)
        at org.codehaus.commons.compiler.Cookable.cook(Cookable.java:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:887)
        ... 35 more

Driver stacktrace:)
17/06/30 19:28:36 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
17/06/30 19:28:36 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
17/06/30 19:28:36 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
17/06/30 19:28:36 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
17/06/30 19:28:36 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
17/06/30 19:28:36 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
17/06/30 19:28:36 INFO AMRMClientImpl: Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
... so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `Dataframe`s then you can do it using `when` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

```
dataframe
  .withColumn("newColumn", 
    when(col("partition_date") === current_timestamp(), call_CDC).otherwise(lit(""))
  )
```

**Edited**

There are some improvements needed in your code and foreach is creating the memory overhead. Try following code, should be lighter than the one you are using

```
//function for uniform null values
def replace(Colm :Column) = when(Colm==="null" || Colm==="NULL" || Colm==="" || Colm==="Null" || Colm==="\\N", lit(null)).otherwise(Colm)

val rawdata_sql = "select  "+ rawDataTableColumns + ",md5(concat_ws(''," + rawDataTableStrColumns+")) as Hash_Column, current_timestamp as LAST_MDF_DT from "+ rawDataTableName + " where partition_date='" + folderDate + "'"
var batch_data = hqlContext.sql(rawdata_sql)

val tocheckCols = batch_data.schema.filter(f => f.dataType == DataTypes.StringType)
tocheckCols.map(c => {
  batch_data = batch_data.withColumn(c.name, replace(col(c.name)))
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
It works fine with small tables but fails with below error when applied on large Dataframe (281 columns):

"org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering" grows beyond 64 KB

Comment: I would like to see you CDC so can you update with CDC and what you did and the error message in the question?

Comment: The main objective here is to replace string 'null'  or blank spaces with NULL in the batch dump
As far as CDC is concerned its successful without using adding above functionality. Still I am adding the piece of code in the question in case there can be any workaround.
Thanks

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18492

Some folks have discussed the issue at above link but I am not able to figure out any resolution as such..

Comment: Hi Ramesh Thanks for another approach but this is also throwing same error.

Comment: check https://www.tapatalk.com/topic/1600132-nabble-apache-spark-user-list/817d192a590d6d875f3d852c550d21ee-re-spark-sql-core-rdd-to-dataset-1500-columns-data-with-createdataframe-throw-exception-of-grows-beyond-64-kb and there is patch in https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18119

Comment: Hi Ramesh 
Thanks again for your time.
Now I was able to overcome this issue by carrying out cleansing process and joins for CDC on different dataframes.
I first cleansed the table for replacing string 'null' or blank spaces with NULL and then overwrote the table in place. Then I created another Dataframe for the new cleansed table and performed my CDC involving joins (4) on it.